# C++17 lambda captures with relaxed type requirements

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, c++17

I have got a following code, that does compile with C++17 compiler but will not with C++14. I am wondering what was the change, that allowed following code to compile:

```
struct Foo{
  Foo()=default;
  Foo(const Foo&)=default;// copy by const ref 
};

struct Bar{
  Bar()=default;  
  Bar(Bar&)=default; //copy by non const
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  Bar bar;
  Bar barcpy = bar;
  auto foolam = [foo]{};
  auto barlam = [bar]{}; //compiles only with C++17
}
```

Is there any exact proposal for this code to compile or it is by the way of some other feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Guaranteed Copy Elision](https://wg21.link/p0135r0) (with [wording](https://wg21.link/p0135r1)). The lambda here is actually a red herring.

In C++14, this:

```
auto barlam = [bar]{};
```

still requires move-construction to be valid (even if you don't want the move and the move is likely to be elided anyway). But that lambda isn't move-constructible, because `Bar` isn't move-constructible. `Foo` *is* move-constructible, so `foolam` works fine.

A non-lambda version of this would be:

```
auto bar = Bar{}; // error in C++14
auto foo = Foo{}; // ok
```

In C++17, this isn't move construction - we just directly initialize the target object. In one sense, we're eliding the move. In a difference sense, there actually is no move by the language rules at all. So this:

```
auto bar = Bar{};
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
Bar bar{};
```

The same holds for the lambda.

Comment: awesome. Thanks! I was aware of the guaranteed copy Elision, but I would have never guessed this is the reason, why this is like that.